# How to change Date Picker default date format in Flutter

Tags: flutter, date, dart, flutter-web

I want to change the default date picker date format. The default format of date picker is "MM/DD/YYYY". But i want "DD/MM/YYYY".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by updating your apps (or just the widgets) locale:

```dart
await showDatePicker(locale: const Locale('de'));
```

`'de'` for germany, but pick whatever countryCode you require.

Comment: Don't you need to specify MaterializationDelegates in your root MaterialApp widget? Or is this optional?
MaterializationDelegates are; 


            localizationsDelegates: const [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],

Answer (score 2):

so in order to display the date format.
for e.g:

```
Text( '${DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate)}'),
```

check out DateFormat docs at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html for your format
.

Answer (score 1):

You can use locales for this, pass english locale but GB version to your showDatePicker method.

```
await showDatePicker(locale: const Locale('en', 'GB'));
```